# Apache CXF mapping HTTP header parameters to Bean fields

Tags: jax-rs, cxf

I have a service class similar to below.

```
@Component
@Path("/employees/")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class EmpService {
    @POST
    public Response addEmployee(Emp emp) {
     // some code here to add Emp.
    }
}

@XmlRootElement
public class Emp {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    // etc.,
}
```

I also have a requirement to read several custom HTTP header parameters and include it in my method's business logic. I read about annotations to pass the header paramters using @HeaderParam or with @Context HttpHeaders. In either of these options it would require a change in method signature to pass the extra args in addEmployee() method which i would like to avoid.

Instead is there any option to inject then in my Emp object itself(something similar to below snippet) ?

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Emp {

    @HeaderParam("myParam1")    // some thing similar to these
    private String headerParam1;
    @HeaderParam("myParam2")
    private String headerParam2;

    // To be mapped from HTTP body payload
    private String name;
    private String age;
    // etc.,
}
```

Comment: Simple answer. No. The params annotated fields need to be in a separate bean from the body bean, and the bean type should be annotated with `@BeanParam` in the method signiature

Comment: Thanks, so is it possible to define a separate bean to map all header parameters? something like public Response addEmployee(Header header, Emp emp) ?? if so could you please provide some example code

Comment: You need that annotation `@BeanParam Header header`. Note this is only available in JAX-RS 2.0